# TideSDK doesn't recognize SDK on Mountain Lion

Tags: tidesdk

I tryed to start the hello world example but I got this error:

[image]

I have installed the SDK on the location that the get started guide recommend (~/Library/Application Support/TideSDK). There is something I am doing wrong, can you help me please?

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Heads up!
You need to store the downloaded SDK in

```
~/Library/Application Support/TideSDK
```

Thats the library folder inside your user folder, and NOT the global library folder.

You can find more information about setting up TideSDK and getting started with your first app under: http://tidesdk.multipart.net/docs/user-dev/generated/#!/guide/getting_started